# 'Unable to play an audio file in Nuxt.js app'

Tags: html, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am working on a simple nuxt.js project that plays two audio files and asks the user to determine the audio interval between them. I am currently unable to play any audio files. I took in this solution (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration/#extend-webpack-to-load-audio-files) but its not working

also I added in nuxt.config.js

```
  loaders: {
      vue: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          audio: 'src',
        },
      },
    },
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      })
    }
```

and here my code

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-2">
            <audio
              src="@/assets/audios/podcast1.mp3"
              controls
              class="audio my-3"
            ></audio>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please be more explicit on `its not working`?

Comment: Hi kissu, In my code  given file path like src: " @/assets/audios/postcast1.mp3" this path is not working , when I put url ( src: " https/somemp3adio") its working properly , don`t know where i am making mistake,      and in inspect element getting    <audio data-v-33f49e51="" src="[object Module]" controls="controls" class="audio my-3"></audio>

Answer (score 3):

I disabled the esmodule then my audio file working

In nuxtconfigure do like this

```js
extend(config, ctx) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
      esModule: false,
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. But in my case, I play the sound alert from the code.
This code worked previously:

```
const audio_file = require('@/assets/beeps/some_beep.mp3')
const beep = new Audio(audio_file)
beep.play()
```

But after the update stopped working.
Fix the problem helped:

```
const audio_file = require('@/assets/beeps/some_beep.mp3').default
```

I learned it here:
https://amjohnphilip.medium.com/how-to-work-with-audio-files-in-nuxt-js-8da7abb3c5bb